# send parameters from extjs to PHP file (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, extjs

I have a problem with my code.
I use ExtJs and Codeigniter to develop my web App
Actually my problem is sending parameter from extjs to CI Controller. 
I have a simple code like this

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../../extjs/src/ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
]);

Ext.define('materialspec', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
             {name: 'id_planmaterial', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'material_desc', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'material_priority', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'material_product_code', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'material_qty', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'material_unit', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'material_note', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'docNo', type: 'string'}
            ]
});

var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    id: 'store2',
    model: 'materialspec',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '../planspec/planmaterial',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'id_planmaterial'
        }
    },
    sorters: [{
        property    : 'id_planmaterial',
        direction   : 'ASC'
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    var encode = false;
    var local = true;

    var filters2 = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        encode: encode,
        local: local,
        filters: [
            {
                type: 'boolean',
                dataIndex: 'id_planmaterial'
            }
        ]
    };

    var grid2 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        border: false,
        store: store2,
        columns: [
            { header: "No.", xtype: 'rownumberer', width: 30, align: 'center' },
            { id: 'docNo', header: "Document No.", dataIndex: 'docNo', sortable: true, filter: {type: 'string'} },
            { id: 'descMaterial', header: "Description", dataIndex: 'material_desc', flex:1, filter: {type: 'string'} },
            { id: 'priority', header: "Priority", dataIndex: 'material_priority', flex:1, filter: {type: 'string'} },
            { id: 'productCode', header: "Product Code", dataIndex: 'material_product_code', flex:1, filter: {type: 'string'} },
            { id: 'qty', header: "Quantity", dataIndex: 'material_qty', flex:1, filter: {type: 'string'} },
            { id: 'unit', header: "Unit", dataIndex: 'material_unit', flex:1, filter: {type: 'string'} },
            { id: 'note', header: "Note", dataIndex: 'material_note', flex:1, filter: {type: 'string'} }
            ],
        loadMask: true,
        features: [filters2],
        title: 'PlanSpec Material',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        renderTo: 'gridMaterial'
    });

    store2.load({
    params:{
        test:2
    }
    });
});
```

And I have a controller like this

```
public function planmaterial(){
        $result = $this->input->post('test');
        echo $result;
    }
```

Actually I think it should be given an output = '2'.
but the output is not showed.
so, what should I do?
please tell me about my false.
thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doing a GET request and using the querystring:

../planspec/planmaterial?test=2

Then, you should use:

```
$this->input->get('test', TRUE);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking in the wrong place, and it appears as though your route has to deal with being called directly and via an XHR.

First, ensure CI is configured to not clobber the `$_GET` super global. It's in `application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
```

Second, in your controller, use the input class to determine if the request is in fact an XHR. You need to know because in one use, you send a variable, and in the other you're sending a JSON response.

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
```

This merely determines if the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header is set.

Finally, you want to get the value from `$_GET`, not `$_POST`, and initialize it:

```
    $result = $this->input->get('test', FALSE);
```

You end up with the following:

```
$value = $this->input->get('test', FALSE);
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request() === TRUE) {
    if ($value === FALSE) {
        /* deal with an improper XHR */
    } else {
        /* deal with a proper XHR, send your JSON */
    }
} else {
    /* Not an AJAX request
     * Adjust your view based on the value of 'test' being set or not. Do you
     * need to do something differently if it isn't set? 
     */
}
```

I'd recommend however that you use different routes, one exclusively for the XHR - at least as far as I can tell by looking at what you posted.